# Como ler um arquivo enviado pelo usuário usando FileInputStream?

Tags: java, jsf, upload, primefaces

Eu gostaria que o usuário enviasse um arquivo .xls para o sistema e a partir deste seria criado um banco de dados.
O método que eu tenho está funcionando, porém o parâmetro que o FileInputStream recebe é uma String indicando o caminho do arquivo. Só que o sistema será utilizado por diferentes máquinas e o arquivo enviado terá diferentes caminhos.

O que eu gostaria de saber é como eu faço para o usuário escolher, a partir de sua máquina, o arquivo que deverá ser lido pelo sistema, ao invés de o sistema pegar o arquivo de um caminho específico (estático).

Segue o método:

```
public void convertePlanilhaEmAlunos() {

        try {

            // ALTERAR O PATH DE ACORDO COM O LOCAL DA PLANILHA
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
                    "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\teste.xls");

            // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                if (row.getRowNum() < 7) {
                    continue;
                }

                for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Cell cell : row) {
                    aluno.setNome(String.valueOf(row.getCell(0)));
                    aluno.setDataNascimento(String.valueOf(row.getCell(1)));
                    aluno.setRg(String.valueOf(row.getCell(2)));
                    aluno.setNomeMae(String.valueOf(row.getCell(3)));
                    aluno.setRgMae(String.valueOf(row.getCell(4)));
                    aluno.setNomePai(String.valueOf(row.getCell(5)));
                    aluno.setCurso(String.valueOf(row.getCell(6)));
                    aluno.setTurma(String.valueOf(row.getCell(7)));

                }

                if (aluno.getNome() == "") {
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println(aluno.getNome());

                criaAluno();

                aluno = new Aluno();

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Porque não usa o componente `Upload` do Primefaces para receber o arquivo do usuário? De uma olhada em http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/basic.xhtml. A partir do `UploadedFile`, é possível obter o `InputStream` (http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/UploadedFile.html).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar a biblioteca do primefaces para o seu projeto e utilizar o componente UploadFile para fazer isso. Faça o download da biblioteca do primefaces diretamente no site: http://www.primefaces.org/

Na sua página Web vai ficar assim:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

  <p:fileUpload value="#{fileUploadView.file}" mode="simple" disabled="true" />

  <p:commandButton value="Submit" ajax="false" actionListener="#{fileUploadView.upload}" disabled="true" />
</h:form>
```

E no Java vai ficar assim:

```
public class FileUploadView {

private UploadedFile file;

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void upload() {
    if(file != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Succesful", file.getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

}

Com isso aí você consegue fazer esse envio de forma mais fácil e no próprio objeto do "UploadedFile" você pode buscar o caminho dele.

Answer (score 0):

Um dos construtores `XSSFWorkbook` recebe um `InputStream` como parâmetro. Dito isso, você pode trocar o `FileInputStream` por um tipo de `InputStream` que lhe sirva melhor, como o `BufferedInputStream` ou outro qualquer.

Depende da sua necessidade e da forma como o usuário vai enviar o arquivo ao servidor. Acredito que o arquivo já chegue ao servidor como `InputStream` e assim você pode passá-lo diretamente ao construtor do `XSSFWorkbook`.